# Creating a priority queue in C++ using STL

Tags: c++

I am learning the use of priority queues using STL. I came across this statement in a code.

`priority_queue<node*,vector<node*>,compare> minHeap;`

Here, the `node` and `compare` is defined as follows:

```
struct node{
    char c;
    int f;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};

class compare{
    public:
   bool operator()(node *l,node *r)
    {
        return (*l).f>(*r).f;
    }
};
```

Now, I want to know what does the first statement mean? (i.e. `priority_queue.....`)

I know its declaring a priority queue but what exactly do the parametres being passed to it mean?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/

Comment: You may look at [en.cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) or [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/).

Comment: Did you look at a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)? The first is the element type, the second is the underlying container, the third is the function type used to compare elements' priorities.

Comment: [OT]: Missing some const in `class compare`.

Answer (score 1):

The template parameters used is also described here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue

The first template parameter (named `T` in the link I supplied) `node*` defines the datatype stored in the queue.

The second template parameter (named `Container` in the link I supplied) defines the container class used store the datatypes. In the example you included, the [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) class is used to store the elements of type `node*` hence the template parameter for this as well. What this means is that the priority queue will internally store the elements in a vector class, you could use any other container classes if you wanted to, as long as they live up to the requirements specified in the concept [`SequenceContainer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/SequenceContainer), and implements the `front`, `push_back` and `pop_back` methods.

The third and last template parameter (named `Compare` in the link I supplied) is a the name of the function object used to do the internal comparison, the operator `()` is called, with the objects to compare-